# can't select table when starting mysql database connection in visual study 2017 for c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, mysql-connector, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

My visual studio 2017 can't load MySQL database.

[image: Already installed MySQL for VS and connector/NET]

But if I pressed next these happened: [image]

when I click next a dialog should appear to select a table, but after I click next a pop up window appears by itself without any response or change. [image: after this the next one appears and suddenly disappears without any change and response]

and i also install extension MySQL [image]

[image]

But if I use Microsoft SQL, Visual Studio can load the DB and tables. How to fix this?

Comment: The NuGet package doesn't install a MySQL designer into Visual Studio, it installs database drivers into the project. You need to install the appropriate Visual Studio extension

Comment: what should i install?
I have installed this
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Comment: I have also installed extensions mysql

Comment: Does [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html) can help you?

Comment: no, i have it installed and still not working